# SQL ADSI Active Directory Create New Accounts

Tags: sql-server, active-directory, adsi

I have an ADSI connection in my SQL Server (2005) and I'm able to query it using openquery.  Is there any way to create new accounts (and/or) edit existing ones?

Also, I'd like to  have to use openquery to get to the data, but it looks like it's the only solution.

Here's a sample query that I'm using:

```
SELECT 
  samaccountname,
  department,
  mail,
   displayName,
  employeeid
FROM OPENQUERY( ADSI, 
  '
  SELECT samaccountname, department, mail,  displayName, employeeid
  FROM ''LDAP://DC=MyDomainName,DC=MyDomainExtension''
  WHERE objectCategory = ''Person'' and objectClass= ''user''
  '
)
```

Thanks

Comment: @kev: This is a system wide edit/change. Do not rollback.

Comment: RichB - so who decided you could make a global change to what was already the more popular of the two tags to something less people were using?

Comment: @RichB - more people using 'activedirectory' over 'active-directory' would seem to be a consensus which you are always so keen to use as one of your usual excuses.

Comment: @Kev: The rules are very clear. Seperate words with a - in the tags. Active Directory is two words.

Comment: And your excuse for replacing the I'm contraction?

Comment: @RichB - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229784/tips-for-effectively-tagging-questions - "Do not re-tag only to change the format of the tag (ie: stackoverflow -> stack-overflow). This is done automatically by the community user."

Comment: @Kev: The community user is somewhat dead. Hasn't worked in a while.

Comment: @Rich B & Kev: Are you two serious about your little edit war? Honestly, isn't it completely irrelevant if it is "I'm or "I am"?

Comment: @Rich B: Editing other peoples posts to change something at this level of insignificance steals them one opportunity to add something *relevant* before their post is turned into a wiki and cannot earn them rep anymore. Maybe (just maybe) you are taking this editing business a little too seriously.

Comment: @Tomalak: That is not how CW works, and this has nothing to do with my edits. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Kev @Rich B: Please end these rollback wars

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't (at least not using ADSI SQL).

ADSI SQL only defines a search interface, supporting nothing more than the `SELECT` statement (See MSDN: "[SQL Dialect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746494(VS.85).aspx)"). Also, `OPENQUERY()` is the only way to get the data in SQL Server.

To create objects, you will have to use another method (you can script against the ADSI interface quite well).